# Have formula copied to entire column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that displays the average of a row, i.e. `=average(c3:al3)` and the function is in column AN3.

I want to copy that function down a row (but need to do this for 560 rows) and I need it to auto change from C3:AL3 to C4:AL4 (if this makes sense). I know I can do it by hand but that would be prohibitively time consuming. I can insert a row into a column wide formula (such as `=average(c3:c560)` and it will auto change it to `=average(c3:561)`) just want to know if can do the same or do it as a bulk action for rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing is to copy and paste; the change from `c3:al3` to `c4:al4`, etc, will happen automatically. I would proceed as follows:

1. Enter the formula `=average(c3:al3)` in `AN3`.
2. Select cell `AN3`, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
   on Mac) to copy it (the cell itself, not the formula from the formula line).
3. Select the range `AN3:AN562` (or whichever range you want to paste to).
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac).

The formula that will actually appear in the cells will have appropriate row numbers.

---

A mouse-based way to do the same is to drag the formula down using the dot in the bottom right corner of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can double click on the little square that appears when you select a cell and automatically repeats all available rows down.

Comment: He?? .... who??

Comment: This [applies](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db#bmfillformulas) to Excel but **does not apply** on Google spreadsheets.

Comment: It works fine to me (in the Spanish version of Google spreadsheets).

Comment: @Fernando **You are correct**. My mistake. I will not delete my comment though as a reference to others (in case they make the same mistake as I did).

Comment: Please clarify in your answer that: _The above trick **only works** for clusters of not empty rows_.  This is never mentioned in the original question.